# Node/Express - IP Restrict Access to Routes But Not Static Files

Tags: node.js, express

In my MEAN app, i have an API and static web files e.g. `index.html` and `login.html`.

```
//Routes
app.use('/mysuperapi', require('./routes/api'));

//For static files
app.use(express.static('site'));
```

If I didn't want users to be able to go URLs such as `mysite.com/mysuperapi` freely - i'm wondering is this is possible if at all?

Pages such `login.html` that call an authenticate route in the API would happen from the user's machine, so I can't exactly whitelist all IPs expect my servers.

Or are all APIs simply public?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can restrict access to routes by adding another middleware layer, for instance

```
app.use('/mysuperapi/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // do your filtering here, call a `res` method if you want to stop progress or call `next` to proceed
    var ip = req.ip || 
             req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
             req.connection.remoteAddress || 
             req.socket.remoteAddress ||
             req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;

     // Your allowed ip. You can also check against an array
     if (ip == '5.4.3.2') {
       next();
     } else {
        res.end();
     }
}

app.use('/mysuperapi', require('./routes/api'));

// ... the rest of your code
```

the function on the first app.use statement will be called for every path that matches the pattern and before it reaches your API, so you can restrict access there.

Comment: Great, that looks clear. But i can't seem to understand something. If some user is on the login page and they call the auth route, then I must allow their IP. So does this mean I won't really be able to restrict the API to only users accessing through the site?

Comment: To add to this - the whole purpose of blocking is I don't want the API to be 'bashed' e.g. if someone knew the auth route they could surely try a million usernames and passwords.

Comment: If what you want is to restrict access only from your site, then you might want to set your access control headers to just receive calls from your site, i.e. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yoursite.com`. You can look here for reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin